# ruby rvm requirements

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

Running rvm requirements says I need to brew install all these

```
# For ruby:
brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 libtool 
pkg-config openssl readline libyaml sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba
```

how do I know if I already have these on my computer and I won't be wasting space downloading them again?  For instance I know mountain lion comes with sqlite if I `brew install sqlite` will that overwrite the sqlite already on the computer or install another copy?  I'm running Mac 10.8.2,  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not uninstall anything. Brew keeps it's packages separate and creates symlinks to `/usr/local`. you could run `whereis autoconf`, `whereis sqlite`, etc. to make sure that the required packages are installed and properly loaded in the environment then use homebrew to install the rest. Although your older packages should suffice, if the ruby installation fails you should use homebrew to install everything as it will ensure that all packages are compatible.

Comment: Is there a way to uninstall these after instillation using homebrew.

Comment: @user1096509 homebrew will update the symlinks to the binaries in your bash profile so the homebrew binaries will be the default for all general purposes (like when you are in a bash shell). The system binaries should probably not be removed because it's always possible certain system components depend on them. homebrew installations are also very easy to uninstall if you want to revert to the system binaries.